# Cascading MODELS in ASP.NET MVC 5 - Architectural Advice NEEDED

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

Consider a View V and its associated imported ViewModel VM. This view is for a financial document submission process and contains several fields, and the viewmodel VM contains a property of a list of customers, List>Customer>, that is loaded from the database at startup and populates a dropdownlist. V loads, and the user picks a customer C from the list List>C>. Immediately, the form is submitted persisting C.Id and is redirected to a HttpGet ActionResult that uses C.Id to fill a dropdownlist from the database containing all Item Ids List>I> previously ordered from this customer. This list is stored in VM. The user chooses an item I from this dropdownlist. Immediately, the form is submitted persisting I.Id and is redirected to a HttpGet ActionResult that uses C.Id and I.Id to retrieve the price associated with this item, I.Price, from the database and fills it in a textbox on V.

The above was easy. Now is where it really gets difficult. The user fills out the quantity of I they want to file a financial submission for, writes a comment in a nearby textbox, and presses an "add item" button which will then reload the form showing the item in a HTML table on the form for all to see, while C.Id is still listed in its dropdownlist. The company expects multiple items to be added to the form at one time before the final submission is done. Now, I have to persist an Item OBJECT (carrying 5-6 fields) as well as a LIST>ITEM> while more items are being added to this list. The goal is, I can submit this to a table Submission, S, containing S.Id that will show the customer, address info, SubmissionId, and several other fields, and will also submit all the items to a related SubmissionItem table that will also contain the same SubmissionId to track the submissions.

I have absolutely no idea how to carry through the second paragraph. I don't think it's possible. In a desktop application, it's a piece of cake, but on the web I can't get the forms to persist! My only thought was to remove all Data Annotations and just never refresh the view on RedirectToAction methods, but that is not PRG protocol. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use javascript to add rows with form fields (in table or hidden) so they're ready to go when form is submitted. The VM would have a list or similar type to display returning sessions.

Another option is to utilize async operations for every addition and subtraction.